# How can I tell if my SNES games are fake?

Tags: snes

I'm thinking about selling my collection of SNES and N64 games - so I've been looking for signs to tell whether my games are fake or not and was left with a great amount of games I think might be fake. Here is an overview of my suspected-games:

[image: suspected games]

All these games' boxes are slimmer than my other original ones and is protected by transparent plastic inside the box instead of the fragile well-known white plastic ones. I am generally low with manuals because I at the time thought they were useless (...yea) but none of these games has one (out of 100+ I got maybe 8, so it could be random).

Here is a closer look at what I've got and why I'm confused. Metal warrior, slim box, transparent inside-box, looks american by the text and the nintendo-sign, however, the cartridge label behind is all japanese - what is going on? Is the box fake, the cartridge, or both/none?

[image]

Christmas daze, we have no nintendo-sign, the cover picture is very different from what I see on ebay, the label is not completely alligned with the game - seems obvious fake, however, the game still has that japanese label behind.

*picture missing as I can only paste 2

The last one I will show is Mickey no tokyo, the box is in japanese, the game is in japanese, the picture matches ebay - looks real, though japanese.

*picture missing as I can only post 2

I hope someone can clear it up to me - maybe it's just the boxes that are fake? I can't find much about slim boxes, so I will try here. If anyone wants to have a closer look at more of the games, we can do it here(if possible, I'm new) or exchange e-mails. (sorry for grammar)
BR

Comment: You would have to analyze each one by itself.  More importantly open the caritage up and inspect the pcb

Comment: Ramhound: Thanks, I will look into that then! Just thought maybe someone had seen the slim-boxes before.

Comment: There's my upvote; hopefully you'll be on your way to being able to post more than two images per question — then maybe you can show us some more info.  Of course, you could upload the images to [Imgur](https://imgur.com) anyway, and link them here …

Answer (score -1):

I take it from your post that you live in Brazil? I'm not familiar with the original releases of games in South America, but I have to say I'm a little suspicious of the Metal Warriors box saying "for sale and use in Canada, USA, Mexico and Latin America", which was very typical of American boxes, but that's obviously not an American Metal Warriors box.

This is typical of American games, but your mileage may vary: For boxes and manuals, pay attention to their print quality. With the exception of Majesco re-launches (officially licensed and therefore "real", but basically just reprints), the image quality on a box is typically high resolution. Grainy prints or white box insides instead of grey-brown composite paper is suspect. If your manuals aren't semi-gloss and look like they were printed from an inkjet printer, that's also pretty suspect.

You may find people with better or closer to home opinions on NintendoAge (http://nintendoage.com), a forum for collectors, many of which have unique collecting goals. In the event your games are all real, you might even find a buyer.